# Installing KDE with Qubes

Tags: qubes

I've installed Qubes OS and try to install KDE with

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update @kde-desktop-qubes
```

as docs suggest, but it failed at the first try. I then ran into google and found that I've should use

```
sudo dnf install apper breeze-icon-theme colord-kde dolphin kcm_systemd kde-runtime kde-settings-pulseaudio kde-style-breeze kdelibs kdeplasma-addons kdialog khelpcenter khotkeys kinfocenter kmenuedit kmix konsole5 kscreen ksysguard kwin phonon-qt5-backend-gstreamer plasma-breeze plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-doc plasma-pa plasma-user-manager plasma-workspace polkit-kde qt5-qdbusviewer sddm sddm-breeze sddm-kcm sni-qt
```

I tried that and it installed some 300MB successfully just to find out that I've should use something else(below) instead and the previous method of installing lots of packages with dnf on dom0 is a big mistake.

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update kde-settings-qubes
```

So I did run this command and it successfully finished, but I don't get any visual changes. Do I need to do something else?

What exactly the way to install latest qubes with kde please?

Update: I'm currently re-installing qubes, because I'm getting some very odd behavior of the system(not shutting/restarting properly etc).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am 2 months late, the 2 months where my windows decided to die.
Okay look just run these commands in `dom0`:

```
sudo systemctl disable lightdm
sudo systemctl enable sddm
```

Thanks to you, I can enjoy the desktop too!

Comment: I did this and like KDE much more than the outdated xfce.  For me KDE runs as well or better than xfce.  When following the above I ran into a problem. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730625/qubes-os-correct-way-to-start-qvm-start-gui-service-with-kde

Comment: To make it useful I also had to `sudo apt install kde-baseapps` as some of the apps intended for XFCE no longer work. IMO this installed far too much so there may be a less bloated way to do this.